# Do i need to be a partner to develop and distribute connected apps?

Tags: rest-api, appexchange, connected-apps

If I do not want to use Appexchange as a distribution mechanism, do I need to be a partner to develop and distribute connected apps?

I have gone through all the documentation available on the Salesforce site but I could find nothing preventing me from distributing my connected app without being a partner.  The connected app that I created in my developer org seems to work in most of my production/sandbox test environments.

Looking for any advice on if I need to take care of something.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you mean a (managed) package or literally "Connected App" (metadata type)?

Comment: I meant an app that uses oauth to talk to Salesforce rest APIs

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to be a partner in order to use the API. I knew of a number of companies that had products that integrated with Salesforce, but had to be installed/connected directly from their website, though I can't recall a specific one right now. Being a partner [does come with perks](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/appinnovators/AppExchange_ISV_Program_Benefits_4) which can substantially increase your revenue and product visibility, but if you don't care about that or don't want to bear the costs associated with actually being a Partner, you don't need to bother.

Answer (score -1):

By Connected App, do you mean a managed package ?
If yes, yes you can distribute it as you want, because all a client needs to have your package is an installation link.

But usually, it reassures clients that you passed the Security Review necessary to appear on AppExchange, and it also reassures clients to see your app on AppExchange :)

Comment: For [non-approved managed packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.appExchangeInstallGuide.meta/appExchangeInstallGuide/appexchange_install_notification.htm) there are specific Ts and Cs.

Comment: According to the comment on the question, this does not provide an answer. I suggest you delete it or update to answer the question.